# Get `Element type is invalid: expected a string ` error when using react-redux-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-redux` from this repo https://github.com/reacttraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux to route my application.
But I always get below error in my browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Below is the source code of `App` component. All these codes are the front end:

```
const history = createHistory();
const rMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
const logger = createLogger({
  log: 'info',
});

const store = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk, authMiddleware, rMiddleware, logger)
)(createStore)(combineReducers({...reducers, router: routerReducer}));

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the Home component code:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Home</div>;
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: Can we see Home & Login?

Comment: I have updated the source code.

Comment: I'm currently on the react-router learning-curve. Always when I get this  error it's a path mistake in my import statements (I'm using ES6 modules). You're not showing those here though.

Answer (score 3):

Ok finally found out the issue. It because of a version miss-match. I should use `"react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",` instead of version `4.x.x` since it is not compatible with react-router 4.x.x.